# Only one of the object's parameters is posted

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

I'm fairly new to android development let alone Retrofit 2.0

I am trying to POST data to a local API (Using deployd), following this tutorial
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

After the code runs, only one parameter of the object "user" (username) is posted and can be seen in the API.

Here's my service interface:

```
public interface serviceInterface{
    String BASE_URL = "http://192.168.0.109:2403";

    @POST("/myojapi")
    Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);

    class myInstance { //just for accessing the methods in the interface

        public static serviceInterface getInstance() {
            Retrofit retrofit = new     Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();

            serviceInterface service = retrofit.create(serviceInterface.class);
            service = retrofit.create(serviceInterface.class);
            return service;
        }
    }

    class User {

        @SerializedName("username")
        String uName;

        @SerializedName("password")
        String uPassword;

        public User(String username, String password) {
            this.uName = username;
            this.uPassword = password;
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my button's code, onResponse method runs because I can see the Snackbar message (after filling in the username and password EditTexts):

```
    button_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            serviceInterface.User user = new serviceInterface.User(editText_username.getText().toString(), editText_passsword.getText().toString());
            Call<serviceInterface.User> call = serviceInterface.myInstance.getInstance().createUser(user);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<serviceInterface.User>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<serviceInterface.User> call, Response<serviceInterface.User> response) {

                    Snackbar.make(v, "added", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<serviceInterface.User> call, Throwable t) {

                }

            });
        }
    });
```

This is the data as seen on deployd (id is automatic), as you can see, password is always empty:

[image]

and this is how the JSON API looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in Deployd, the password field is default and it never showed any value, creating a new field called uPassword worked.